# Create header.php redirect in Wordpress and with WPML

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, plugin-wpml

I'm developing a website and I'm using WPML to create different languages on the website. I would like to Geo redirect users based on their countries.

I'm using subdirectories in WPML so I have:

www.mydomain.com

www.mydomain.com/ie/

www.mydomain.com/ca/

I created a script that allows me to get the IP and get a country's code into a variable ([this is what I'm using](https://dev.maxmind.com/#GeoIP2)), I also created a header redirect with this script. This is what I put in my functions.php file:

```
add_action ('wp_loaded', 'my_redirect_function');

function my_redirect_function() {

  $ip = '';

     if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
     {
       $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
     }
     elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
     {
       $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     }
     else
     {
       $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     }

     $country = file_get_contents('http://geoip.maxmind.com/a?l=6QT6fNSdtMVw&i='.$ip);

     if( $country == 'IE' ) {

         wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') . "/ie/" );

         exit;

     }

}
```

I don't know why I get an endless loop.

Comment: You don't need to run `my_redirect_function()` again when already redirected to the language directory. Check referrer or directory you are in.

Answer (score 1):

Your code redirects to "/ie/" also if you are already on "/ie/". The easiest way to prevent this is by changing

```
if( $country == 'IE' ) {
```

to

```
if( $country == 'IE' && substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 4 ) != '/ie/' ) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I tried to change it, now I don't get the endless loop but I'm not redirected anymore. when I type "www.mydomain.com" I'm not redirected to "www.mydomain.com/ie", any idea?

Comment: That was my mistake sorry. I used the wrong logical operator. It has to be != instead of ==. I corrected my code